# Convert format of data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data file in the following format

```
id     col1     col2     col3

1      abc      abc2     
2      abc      abc3     abc2
3      abc2
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
id    abc     abc2     abc3

1     TRUE    TRUE     FALSE
2     TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
3     FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
```

How can I do this using R (or anything else)? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have not specified in sufficient detail what you want to achieve. IF your intention was to replace the abc... entries with TRUE and those positions where there is "nothing" with FALSE, then the id=3 line in the desired output should read "3 TRUE FALSE FALSE". Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @user465139 Yes, you identified what I want to achieve correctly, except for one small detail. id=3 row is specified correctly in the question. It has only abc2 in the original data set, and so only that column in the modified data set contains TRUE. Hence, it is FALSE TRUE FALSE.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to dump your dataframe reproducibly, instead of us having to recreate it. Otherwise we have no way of telling whether the empty cells have whitespace or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
            gather(Var, Val, col1:col3) %>%
            filter(grepl('[^ ]+', Val)) %>%
            spread(Val, Var)

df1[,-1] <- !is.na(df1[,-1])
df1
#  id   abc abc2  abc3
#1  1  TRUE TRUE FALSE
#2  2  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#3  3 FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1= c('abc', 'abc', 'abc2'),
      col2= c('abc2', 'abc3', ' '), col3=c('   ', 'abc2', ''))
```

Comment: I don't think it is what he expects: as I understand, he would like to have F T F in the third row because just abc2 appears, so the T goes just in the second column. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('abc','abc','abc2'),
                 col2=c('abc2','abc3',''),
                 col3=c('','abc2','') )

df != ''
     col1  col2  col3
[1,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I don't think it is what he expects: as I understand, he would like to have F T F in the third row because just abc2 appears, so the T goes just in the second column. Please, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('abc','abc','abc2'),
             col2=c('abc2','abc3',''),
             col3=c('','abc2','') )

lev <- unique(unlist(df))

lev <- lev[ lev != '']

output <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x)    lev %in% x))
dimnames(output) <- list(id = rownames(df), lev)
```

This should give the outcome you expect:

```
output

id    abc abc2  abc3
  1  TRUE TRUE FALSE
  2  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
  3 FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean.  I was just looking at smci's answer.  My bad!